# JSON API plugin, Get posts by category return no post

Tags: json, categories, plugin-json-api

Im trying to get the posts by category. using this URL:

```
/api/core/get_category_posts/?slug=cat2
```

But responding this:

```
{"status":"ok","count":0,"pages":0,"category":{"id":3,"slug":"cat2","title":"Cat2","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":7},"posts":[]}
```

Posts are empty! any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get_category_posts/?slug=cat1&post_type=project
```

I forgot to set post_type.